# Hang during GNUMake called from a debian rules file

Tags: objective-c, debian, gnu-make

I am trying to build both a GNUmake and a standard make file from within a debian rules file. Both build fine from command line, ie 'make -f Makefile' and 'make'. But when called from a dpkg-buildpackage:

```
This is gnustep-make 2.6.2. Type 'make print-gnustep-make-help' for help.
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/amon/Work/myapp/MyaApp.app-3.00'
Making all for app MyApp...
 Creating MyApp.app/....
 Compiling file AppController.m ...
 Compiling file LEDCell.m ...
 Compiling file Controller.m ...
 Compiling file MyApp_main.m ...
 Linking app MyApp ...
 Creating MyApp.app/Resources...
 Creating stamp file...
 Creating MyApp.app/Resources/Info-gnustep.plist...
```

It then hangs forever while utilizing 100% of CPU resources for one of the processors. I am suspecting an ENV issue of some sort but have not yet found anything that appears relevant.

I have not found where in the PC/Gorm make structure this happens, but here is the lead up to lockup which I can get with a -d on the make in the debian/rules file:

```
Putting child 0x024091c0 (shared-instance-stamp-string) PID 11784 on the chain.
Live child 0x024091c0 (shared-instance-stamp-string) PID 11784 
Creating stamp file...
Reaping winning child 0x024091c0 PID 11784 
Removing child 0x024091c0 PID 11784 from chain.
  Successfully remade target file `shared-instance-stamp-string'.
  Considering target file `MyAppInfo.plist'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `MyAppInfo.plist'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `MyAppInfo'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `MyAppInfo.cplist'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `MyAppInfo'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `MyAppInfo.cplist'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `MyAppInfo.cplist'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   No implicit rule found for `MyAppInfo.plist'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `MyAppInfo.plist'.
  No need to remake target `MyAppInfo.plist'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `MyApp.app/Resources/Info-gnustep.plist'.
Must remake target `MyApp.app/Resources/Info-gnustep.plist'.

Putting child 0x0240c060 (MyApp.app/Resources/Info-gnustep.plist) PID 11786 on the chain.
Live child 0x0240c060 (MyApp.app/Resources/Info-gnustep.plist) PID 11786 
Creating MyApp.app/Resources/Info-gnustep.plist...
Reaping winning child 0x0240c060 PID 11786 
Live child 0x0240c060 (MyApp.app/Resources/Info-gnustep.plist) PID 11788
```

In case it is useful, when I control C out of the lockup, I get the following sequence:

```
Live child 0x0207c900 (internal-all) PID 11740 
Live child 0x02468f80 (MyApp.all.app.variables) PID 11742 
make[3]: *** Deleting file `MyApp.app/Resources/Info-gnustep.plist'
Live child 0x0240c060 (MyApp.app/Resources/Info-gnustep.plist) PID 11788 
Reaping losing child 0x0240c060 PID 11788 
make[3]: *** [MyApp.app/Resources/Info-gnustep.plist] Interrupt
Removing child 0x0240c060 PID 11788 from chain.
Reaping losing child 0x02468f80 PID 11742 
make[2]: *** [MyApp.all.app.variables] Interrupt
Removing child 0x02468f80 PID 11742 from chain.
Reaping losing child 0x0207c900 PID 11740 
make[1]: *** [internal-all] Interrupt
Removing child 0x0207c900 PID 11740 from chain.
make: *** [build-stamp] Interrupt
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build died from signal 2
```

To eliminate all of my own code and debian scripts from the problem, I have downloaded the TalkSoup.app source package and attempted the same build with it. I get the same problem. Here is the relevant portion of a ps axf

```
 8738 ?        S      0:00              \_ /usr/bin/xterm
 8742 pts/9    Ss     0:00              |   \_ bash
10241 pts/9    S+     0:00              |       \_ /bin/bash /usr/bin/fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage -k<mykey> -pgp
10256 pts/9    S+     0:00              |           \_ /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/dpkg-buildpackage -k<mykey> -pgp
10454 pts/9    S+     0:00              |               \_ /usr/bin/make -f debian/rules build
10456 pts/9    S+     0:00              |                   \_ /bin/sh /usr/bin/gs_make
10457 pts/9    S+     0:00              |                       \_ make
10458 pts/9    S+     0:00              |                           \_ /bin/sh -c (operation=all; \   abs_build_dir="."; \ for directory in TalkSoupBundles Source Input Output InF
10459 pts/9    S+     0:00              |                               \_ /bin/sh -c (operation=all; \   abs_build_dir="."; \ for directory in TalkSoupBundles Source Input Output
10584 pts/9    S+     0:00              |                                   \_ make -C Source -f GNUmakefile --no-print-directory --no-keep-going all GNUSTEP_BUILD_DIR=. _GNUSTEP_
10591 pts/9    S+     0:00              |                                       \_ /bin/sh -c (make -f GNUmakefile --no-print-directory --no-keep-going \ internal-master-app-all \
10592 pts/9    S+     0:00              |                                           \_ make -f GNUmakefile --no-print-directory --no-keep-going internal-master-app-all GNUSTEP_BUI
10593 pts/9    S+     0:00              |                                               \_ /bin/sh -c ( \ instance=TalkSoup; \ operation=all; \ type=app; \ abs_build_dir="."; \ if
10594 pts/9    S+     0:00              |                                                   \_ make -f GNUmakefile --no-print-directory --no-keep-going internal-app-all GNUSTEP_TY
10632 pts/9    S+     0:00              |                                                       \_ /bin/sh -c (if [ -r "TalkSoupInfo.plist" ]; then \    plmerge TalkSoup.app/Resou
10633 pts/9    R+     4:37              |                                                           \_ plmerge TalkSoup.app/Resources/Info-gnustep.plist TalkSoupInfo.plist
```

Comment: What is happening in that `Creating MyApp.app/Resources/Info-gnustep.plist...` target?

Comment: I am not really sure as it is buried inside the Project manager info. What I can find is that it appears in the PC.project file and the file MyAppInfo.plist contains application info.

Comment: Perhaps I can find something by adding a -d in my debian/rules file at the make.

Comment: Okay, I added that output above.

Comment: What process do you see running in `ps` when this is hung? Is it `cat`?

Comment: 14041 amon      20   0  486276 360572   4944 R 100.0  2.9   0:41.23 plmerge

Comment: I didn't know anything about `plmerge` before this but reading about it I don't see how it could possibly spin forever. Can you trace that process and see what it is doing while it is spinning?

Comment: I've now tried building directly from someone elses source debian, ie TalkSoup.app and I have the same issue. I have placed some of the ps axf above.

Comment: I also tried attaching gdb to the running plmerge process. backtrace seems to show it is running away for some unspecified fault or condition:  #75957 0x00002abc3313e578 in objc_exception_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libobjc.so.4
#75958 0x00002abc32bb894f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgnustep-base.so.1.24
#75959 0x00002abc32bb85e6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgnustep-base.so.1.24

Comment: I've also tried to get in touch with the packager of TalkSoup.app to see if he had any suggestions, but I have had no reply.